# How to measure the length of a call stack?

Tags: recursion

Recently had a test question asking "how deep" the call stack for fact1  where n = 5. Here is the code:

```
int fact1(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return 1
    }
    else {
        return n * fact(n-1)
    }
}
```

The answer on the test was 5, but I believe it is 4. I don't believe the first call is to be counted in the number of calls.

Comment: "*I don't believe the first call is to be counted in the number of calls.*" why not? Is it not part of the callstack? You'd have `fact1(5) -> fact1(4) -> fact1(3) -> fact1(2) -> fact1(1)` - how is the first one not like the others? If you exclude it you have a reason to exclude it, then you'd start at `fact1(4)` but wouldn't the same reason apply to that call as well?

Comment: The function in your example is named `fact1`, but refers to a function named `fact`. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, every function call ends in the call stack.

Your example looks like C; in C, there is always a `main` function; even the `main` function ends on the call stack.

I don't think there is a way to examine the call stack in C; especially since the compiler is allowed to optimise away whatever it wants. For instance, it could optimise tail-recursion, and then the call stack would be smaller than you'd expect.

In Python the call stack is easy to examine; just crash the function whenever you want, by throwing an exception (for instance with `assert(False)`). Then the program will produce an error message containing the full "stack trace", including the list of every function on the stack.

Here is an example of a stack trace in python:

```py
def fact1(n):
    assert(n != 1)
    return n * fact1(n-1)

def main():
    f = fact1(3)
    print(f)

main()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in fact1
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in fact1
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in fact1
AssertionError
```

And another example just for fun:

```py
def print_even(n):
    if (n <= 1):
        print('yes' if n == 0 else 'no')
        assert(False)
    else:
        print_odd(n-1)

def print_odd(n):
    if (n <= 1):
        print('yes' if n == 1 else 'no')
        assert(False)
    else:
        print_even(n-1)

def main():
    n = 5
    print('Is {} even?'.format(n))
    print_even(n)

main()
```

Output:

```
Is 5 even?
no
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in print_even
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in print_odd
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in print_even
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in print_odd
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in print_even
AssertionError
```